# Как разместить header на главном блоке, а не отдельно

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, scss

друзья.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, не могу решить, только position:fixed, но фиксированный хедер мне не нужен. Не знаю, как правильно сформулировать вопрос, поэтому проиллюстрирую:
как получилось у меня, ниже, как нужно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно, чтобы Header был на background блока с информацией.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML HEADER:

```
<header className="header">
    <span className="logo">LOGO</span>
    <nav className="nav-items">
      <ul className="ul-items">
        <li>О нас</li>
        <li>Услуги</li>
        <li>Портфолио</li>
        <li>Награды</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <span className="phone">+800 000 0000</span>      
  </header>


.header {
  color:#FFF;
  padding-top: 32px;  
  max-width: 1600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
    .logo{
      margin-left: 95px;
      font-size: 36px;
    }
    .phone{
      margin-right: 95px;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    
    z-index: 999;
  }




.ul-items {
  li{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 50px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае простым и наилучшим вариантом является position: absolute c шириной width: 100%. После этого хедер встал на то место на которое требовалось.

Answer (score 1):

На удивление довольно часто такое приходится реализовать, но в данном случае на html не решить. Вам придется использовать javascript, и отслеживать scroll страницы. Соответственно, когда scroll достигает определённого значения, Вы меняете стили на `position:fixed`, и также меняете background header.

P.S чтобы сделать элемент прозрачным, но его дочерние элементы имели непрозрачность используйте: `background: rgba(0,0,0,0)` где последний ноль, это прозрачность фона

Comment: Спасибо за ответ
В данном случае простым и наилучшим вариантом является position: absolute c шириной width: 100%. После этого хедер встал на то место на которое требовалось.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, видимо тогда я неправильно понял вопрос, и рассказал как сделать шапку которая меняется при скролле)